# Видеокарта S3 UniChrome Pro для Linux

Tags: драйвер, linux

VIA Technologies, Inc. CN700/P4M800 Pro/P4M800 CE/VN800 [S3 UniChrome Pro] для linux?

Поставил Ubuntu 11.10, глючит очень сильно, виснет... полагаю, что это из-за отсутствия дров VGA. Комп старый, однако может гораздо лучше справляться с работой, нежели без драйверов я думаю.

VIA Technologies, Inc. CN700/P4M800 Pro/P4M800 CE/VN800 [S3 UniChrome Pro] вот модель моей видеокарты, переискал все, что можно, нигде нет. В параметрах системы нет активированных дров вообще, просто пустое окошко... посоветуйте, что можно установить, чтобы система меньше висла, раз уж драйвера не найти мне... :(

Answer (score 1):

В настройках поставить поприетарные драйвера...

[cm10401 driver download](http://www.kashmirobserver.net/logs/cm10401-driver-download.php).

Comment: у меня в настройках в поприетарных драйверах все пусто.Мне нужно установить cm10401 driver, потом активировать его в настройках. Я правильно понял?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант поставить систему 10.04.3 LTS, зачем на старенькое железо ставить достаточно тяжелую версию, которая и на шустрых системах тормозит?Есть также версии Xubuntu, специально для слабых компьютеров.Посмотрите.

Comment: Спасибо. То есть вряд ли у меня все виснет из-за драйверов? Скорее всего просто слишком тяжелая версия убунты для моего ПК, верно?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, версия не тяжёлая, просто с ядром системы проблемы. Я обратил на это внимание, когда только вышла Lynx: при замене ядра на всё, что больше 2.6.33 начинал глючить ввод с клавиатуры - не отображались последние введённые символы и система регулярно "засыпала" - надо было постоянно дёргать мышью. Было ещё немало "чудес". Из последних - на ядре 2.6.32.41 пропал мой "BT-свисток", откатился на 2.6.32.38 - всё снова заработало... Пропали модули для snd_serialmidi... Как вывод - ядро нехило "почистили"... Но на моём "ровере" 10.04 работает, без особых проблем, но пока и без компиза.Как вариант, я пробовал Jolicloud (Joli OS) - это тоже Гигтег 10.04,но с очень неплохой поддержкой железа. Пошаманить, правда пришлось немало, пока привёл к при(в)личному виду, но особых проблем не было. И ещё - там поддержка CN700/VN800... DRM-модуль для ядра, glx-модуль для MESA и "родной" модуль для Иксов...Ubuntu 12.04 beta2 на "ровер" поставилась нормально - её он "тащит" аж со свистом, а вот на Samsung NP-N100 так и не смог поставить с флешки - по всей видимости "теряется" винт на этапе копирования установочных файлов...Мой "ровер" - Partner W500 c 2GB ОЗУ и Intel 2200... Оси - Ubuntu 10.04 (ядро 2.6.32-38.83) и Ubuntu 12.04 beta2 со всеми обновками. И последнее - я обычно "выношу" FireFox - где-то проскакивало "FireFox - пожиратель памяти". Возможно, это тоже одна из причин "тяжеловесности". Ставлю "Opera" и создаю /tmp, /var/log и /var/tmp в ОЗУ.А ещё "выношу" половину автозагрузки. БОльшую половину... :-)